# Integer part of limit of cardinal sine function at 0

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry

I know this very well and also understand how this result arrives:
$$\left\lfloor\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor = 0$$
But, this is what my teacher said:
$$\left\lfloor\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor= 1$$
This is what I found in book!
$$\left\lfloor\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\right\rfloor = 0$$
I am confused here in a basic concept. My teacher said the value of limit is absolute, it is not approaching, so when we put GIF on that it will give 1 as the answer because inside GIF there is 1. But book said the value of limit is approaching to 1 so if we put it in GIF so it will give 0. Which one is right?

Comment: The limit as $x$ goes to 0 of $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ is 1. In your Pic1 do you mean the limit as $n$ goes to infinity of $\frac{sin(n)}{n}$?. This does have a limit of 0.

Comment: Your "Pic 1" 1) should be written in the text instead of being a picture 2) it is not readable : I am unable to say if the variable is an "x" or an "n" 3) $\color{red}{\text{is false !}}$.  The limit is 1 and not zero...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Your teacher's Pic2 is correct. Your Pic1, well, if the [] is floor function, is also correct. But Pic3 is surely wrong, the limit is 1, even floor function cannot help it.

Comment: Picture 3 shows $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left[ \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] .$$  It may well intend that the limit is of the integer part of $\sin x / x$.  Square brackets often mean that.  Since for small $x$ the fraction $\sin x /x < 1$, the integer part will always be zero.

Comment: The edit has damaged the pictures

Comment: @AbelWong In Pic 1, limit is outside the floor function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is wrong.
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 0 \quad \times$$

This one is correct. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

And thus,

$$\left[ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \right]= 1$$

You teacher is correct. after take limit, the result is absolute and = 1. So floor function cannot turn it to $0$.

And as @WA Don mentioned. Since
$$ 0< \frac{\sin x}{x} <1 \quad for \; all \; 0<|x| < \pi $$
$$ \left[ \frac{\sin x}{x} \right] =0 \quad for \; all \; 0<|x| < \pi $$
so $$ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left [\frac{\sin x}{x} \right] = 0$$

Before take limit, it is smaller than 1 provided that $|x|<\pi$ and floor function will turn it into $0$. Then limit of $0$ is still $0$.